# When I try to read the .csv file in flutter, I get an access error

Tags: flutter, csv, file, file-permissions, readfile

when i create the file for the first time on the phone and when i try to read it i don't get any problem and i read it but when i try to read a file that i didn't create through my app, access is denied.
My error is bellow ;

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Bka_data.cvs' (OS Error: Permission
> denied, errno = 13)

**Write function is:**

```dart
Future<void> restore() async {
  final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
  if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    final Database db = await SQLHelper.db();
    await db.delete("spendinfo");
    final fileName = "Bka_data.cvs";
    var path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    final directory = "$path/$fileName";
    final File f = File(directory);
    final List<List<dynamic>> csvData = CsvToListConverter().convert(await f.readAsString());
    final List<spendinfo> lastList = csvData.map((csvRow) => spendinfo.fromCVSObjetct(csvRow)).toList();
    for (var i = 0; i < lastList.length; i++) {
      SQLHelper.createItem(lastList[i]);
      print(lastList[i].id);
    }
  } else {

  }
}
```

**Read function is:**

```dart
Future <void> writeToCvs() async {

  final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
  if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    final Database db = await SQLHelper.db();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> allData = await db.query("spendinfo", orderBy: "id") ;
    final List<List<dynamic>> rows = <List<dynamic>>[];
    var path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    print("dir $path");
    String file = "$path";

    for(final Map<String, dynamic> map in allData) {
      final List<dynamic> row = map.values.toList();
      print(row) ;
      rows.add(row);
    }
    final String fileName = "Bka_data.cvs";
    final directory = "$path/$fileName";
    final File f = File(directory);
    final String cvs = ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
    await f.writeAsString(cvs);
    //print(filePath);
    print("Yüklendi");
  } else {
    // accses is denied
  }
}
```

I tried other kind of permission.

Comment: Your code is using a mix of "cvs" and "csv". The thing you are working with is "csv". Using the right term will avoid confusion and allow you to find help more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your issue, use

> await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

instead of

> await Permission.storage.request();

and add these permissions if you haven't already done so in your
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I was getting an access error when I tried to read the file printed by the application from another application. My problem was solved when I fixed it so that I can't apply it and delete the file after it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, Android Implemented Scoped Storage in which you can not read public files created from other apps directly.

You can use below package to get the file through latest storage access framework -

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_storage